# IE8 Comparability in Magento

Tags: apache, magento, browser, internet-explorer-8

We are facing a problem in our hosting server. May be Apache Setting Problem. Our site is hosted in server company jumba.com.au in here IE8 Compatibility not working. Same code we have tested in hostgator's server. and IE8 is working good on that server. So please can anyone suggest me exactly which apache sttings needed. so that we can ask server company. I have already tried by adding Header set X-UA-Compatible: "IE=EmulateIE7" to httaccess and to end of head section. but It is not working in current server (jumba.com.au) but same code working in hostgator in IE8, when We click proceed to checkout from cart section. then it is always showing shopping cart is empty. this is only IE8 problem and in this server. any suggestion appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked you have cookies enabled in IE8?

Comment: i have changed   // session cookie params
     ' /*  $cookieParams = array(
            'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
            'path'     => $cookie->getPath(),
            'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
            'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
            'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
        );
   */ ' product is adding to cart, but in cart page then we are clicking proceed to checkout it is failed and showing cart empty. it is only in iE8 and only this server,  what is exactly missing in this server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you provide this following code, in the "`head`" element just after the "`title`" element?

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

Hope it helps.